# Can every set of points with rational distance squares be isometrically embedded in $\Bbb Q^d$?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, rational-points

Suppose we are given a finite family of points $p_1,...,p_n\in \Bbb R^d$, so that any two points have a rational distance square, that is,

$$\|p_i-p_j\|^2\in\Bbb Q,\quad\text{for all $i,j\in\{1,...,n\}$}.$$

Is it know whether these points can be isometrically embedded into $\Bbb Q^{D}$ for some sufficiently large $D\ge d$? That is, are there $q_1,...,q_n\in\smash{\Bbb Q^D}$ so that

$$\|p_i-p_j\|=\|q_i-q_j\|,\quad\text{for all $i,j\in\{1,...,n\}$}?$$

If *yes*, what are reasonable lower/upper bounds for $D$?

Comment: There's an obvious strategy:  first embed $n - 1$ points in some $\mathbb Q^{D'}$, then try to enlarge $\mathbb Q^{D'}$ to some $\mathbb Q^D$ with $D \ge D'$ in which we can embed the $n$th point at an appropriate distance.  Do you know an example where this 'greedy' strategy fails, i.e., where a partial embedding cannot be extended?

Comment: @LSpice This works straightforwardly. Make the first point $0$, then the data is equivalent to the dot products of a bunch of vectors. Given $v_1,\dots, v_n$ and the desired dot products for $v_{n+1}$, there is a unique rational vector in the span of $v_1\dots, v_n$ whose dot products with $v_1,\dots, v_n$ are as desired (restrict to a basis and invert the matrix) and $v_{n+1}$ must be this vector plus a vector orthogonal to $v_1,\dots,v_n$. Figure out the norm of this last vector, find a vector in $\mathbb Q^k$ with norm, and sum the existing power of $\mathbb Q$ with $\mathbb Q^k$.

Comment: @WillSawin Even though I already accepted an answer, I would be happy to give this an upvote if posted as an answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following argument gives a bound of $D =4d$, based on a suggestion of LSpice in the comments.

Set $p_1=0$. Using the distances and the fact that $p_1=0$, we can find the dot products $p_i \cdot p_j$, which are all rational.

Assume we've embedded $p_1,\dots,p_k$ in $\mathbb Q^m$ and let's embed $p_{k+1}$. The result will then follow by induction on $k$.

Among $p_2,\dots, p_k$ we can find $r$ of them that form a basis for the space $V_k$ generated by $p_2,\dots, p_k$. Then every vector in $V_k$ whose dot products with these $r$ vectors are rational is a rational linear combination of these vectors (invert the matrix) and thus lies in $\mathbb Q^m$. Hence the projection of $p_{k+1}$ onto $V_k$ lies in $\mathbb Q^m$.

If $p_{k+1}$ lies in $V_k$, we are done. Otherwise, $p_{k+1}$ is equal to its projection onto $V_k$ plus a vector orthogonal to $V_k$. The length-squared of this orthogonal vector is rational. Choose a vector of that length-squared in $\mathbb Q^4$, and let $p_{k+1}$ equal its projection plus this vector in $\mathbb Q^{m+4}$.

The total value of $D$ produced this way is $4d$ since $D$ goes up by $4$ every time $d$ goes up by $1$.

---

For a better value of $D=d+3$, we can use the following trick to reduce the dimension:

Let $W$ be the orthogonal complement in $\mathbb Q^{4d}$ of the vector space generated by $p_1,\dots, p_n$. If we find a vector in $W$ with length $1$, its orthogonal complement is isomorphic, as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$ with quadratic form, to $\mathbb Q^{4d-1}$. Iterating this, we can embed $p_1,\dots, p_n$ into $\mathbb Q^N$ for some $N$ in such a way that $p_1=0$ and the orthogonal complement to the vector space generated by $p_1,\dots, p_n$ contains no vectors of length $1$.

By the Hasse-Minkowski theorem, the only way a positive definite quadratic form over the rationals can fail to represent $1$ is if there is a $p$-adic obstruction for some $p$, which can only happen if the dimension is at most $3$, so the dimension of the orthogonal complement is at most $3$ and $N \leq d+3$, as desired.

Comment: My guess for why $\Bbb Q^4$ is because of Lagrange's four square theorem. Is this correct?

Comment: @M.Winter Indeed, that's what I'm using. I think $D= d+3$ is probably the right bound, though.

Comment: Interesting, what is your intuition behind $d+3$?

Comment: @M.Winter My answer now contains a proof.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. It's well-known fact due to Schönberg that a negative definite kernel on a finite set $X$ (with zero diagonal) can be realized as set of square distances on a Euclidean space. The latter is constructed with an explicit (possibly indefinite) positive scalar product on $\mathbf{R}^X$, which depends linearly on coefficients of the kernel, and modding out by the kernel of this scalar product to get the Euclidean space. So if the kernel is rational, everything remains rational.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the term "kernel on a finite set $X$". Is this a matrix in $\Bbb R^{X\times X}$?

Comment: I am not sure that googling "Schönberg's theorem" led me to the right result. Do you have a keyword to look up the right result?

Comment: @M.Winter: I.J. Schoenberg, On certain metric spaces arising from euclidean spaces by a change of metric and their imbedding in Hilbert space. Ann. Math. 38 (1937), p. 787-793.

Comment: It's also an appendix in the Bekka-Harpe-Valette book (section C.3, see the book at [B.Bekka's page](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/bachir.bekka/KazhdanTotal.pdf))

Comment: @MoisheKohan's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385361/can-every-set-of-points-with-rational-distance-squares-be-isometrically-embedded#comment981822_385365):  [Schoenberg - On certain metric spaces arising from euclidean spaces by a change of metric and their embedding in Hilbert space](https://doi.org/10.2307/1968835).

Comment: I feel that this answer must be missing a step. "Everything remains rational" suggests that we can embed into $\mathbb Q^D$ where $D $ is the dimension of a real embedding (i.e. $D=d$) or at most the number of points $|X|$ (i.e. $D= n$). But neither is true, already for two points whose squared distance is $7$ - we need dimension $4$ since $7$ is not the sum of three rational squares.

Comment: @WillSawin you're right! the answer should be unaccepted :-/

Comment: I mean, one can probably finish from this point by using the Hasse-Minkowski theorem to sum the rational quadratic form with another rational quadratic form and check it is the standard rational quadratic form.